# How to update the tableViewCell data in filtered tableView after search action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `search bar` in `tableview`. On search, I show `tableView` with searched result. Now I select the row from `tableView` and navigate to `detail view` where I show the `textField` with text from `tableCell` selected recently. I update the textfield. and delegate back to previous `tableViewController`. here I want to update that cell in filtered table view and also in the main data array in data source. How to do this in iOS.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same as for non-searched results i.e. `[UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]`, Just using a different index path?

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe, Thats the real challenge for me. How to keep track of indexes in non-searched and searched results?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `UISearchViewController` you need to access the correct table view for your reload operation. A possible solution could be (if you have a property `searchViewController`):

```
[self.searchViewController.searchResultsTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how to keep track of the original data array with the filtered array? I need to update it in both the arrays. How to map the indexpaths of both the arrays. Thats the real challenge for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

In `DetailViewController` add an `@property` in .h like `NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath`,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

set `selectedIndexPath` property of `DetailViewController` in `didSelectRow` method

In `delegate` method add a `NSIndexPath` parameter, like

```
- (void)didUpdatedText:(NSString *)updatedText atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

in tableViewController

**EDIT :**

```
- (void)didUpdatedText:(NSString *)updatedText atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (isSearching) {
        NSString *updatingText = [self.filteredArray elementAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        int elementIndex = [self.dataSourceArray indexOfElement:updatingText];
        [self.dataSourceArray replaceObjectAtIndex:elementIndex withObject:updatedText];
        [self.filteredArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:updatedText];
    } else {
        [self.dataSourceArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:updatedText];
    }
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how to keep track of the original data array with the filtered array? I need to update it in both the arrays. How to map the indexpaths of both the arrays. Thats the real challenge for me.

Comment: Since you are filtering from original data array, the elements in the filtered array have the same reference. So on updating an element in filtered array in turn updates the element in original data array(as early said both have same reference). But here the element itself changes, so tried it in a different way. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

This method will help to relaod data of table at any stage.    `[_tableView reloadData];`